# Is there an alternative to webcamstudio that works on Ubuntu 19.04 and up?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, webcam

I'm looking for a virtual webcam application (similar to what was possible with webcamstudio, which is no longer available or being maintained).

Webcamstudio allowed you to use the v4l loopback device to create a virtual webcam, which you could then use in other applications when no webcam was available (for streaming, for instance). It also supported audio streaming, so you could play a video (with sound) as a virtual webcam.

Is there another application that supports this, and works with Ubuntu 19.04 and up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webcamoid looks promising.  You can find it at:
https://webcamoid.github.io